# Parallelizing calculations on large SF object in Windows environment

Tags: r, sf, parallel-processing

I have a large SF object, containing 1 km x 1 km grid cells, where I need to aggregate the area of polygons within the grid cells, i.e. grouping by grid cell, but also grouping by a second variable, which I call GROUP here (but actually is called something else). I had been using a piped expression (see below), but the sf object is so big that it takes 3 hours to this.

```
What_I_want <- sf_object %>% group_by(ID_GRID, GROUP) %>% summarise(TOTAL_AREA = sum(AREA))
```

I will need to do this 10 times, plus I will need to do other similar piped calculations that take even more time, so I want to try parallel processing to see if I can reduce the time it takes.

I am using Windows 10, with 32 GB RAM and 8 logical cores, and R version 4.1.1. The fact that my computer is Windows excludes, if I understand correctly, the relatively more straightforward parallelization via forking. It’s a shame because the functions presented in the link below would probably work for what I need – they just don’t work on Windows.

Parallelization that is not possible on Windows: https://www.spatialanalytics.co.nz/post/2018/04/01/fixing-st-par/

I have been looking at the some variant of par*apply in the “parallel” package, but I’m open to any package that allows parallelization of sf objects in Windows (Are there other packages?). Mostly I was following the link below, where I tried to have my piped expression inside a function, but I could not get it to work. My attempt to copy this code is wrong – I suspect it might be way off – but I’m groping in the dark here with parallelization.

Parallelization on Windows: https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2020/03/16/parallel-processing-with-r-on-windows/

```
no_cores <- detectCores(logical = TRUE)  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores-2)  
registerDoParallel(cl)
seq_id_all <- seq_along(1:nrow(intersect_2021)) ### intersect_2021 was the file I created with st_intersection. 
aggreg_function <- function(...) {
  library(tidyverse)
  CROP_AREAS <- intersect_2021 %>% group_by(GRID_ID, GROUP) %>% summarise(TOTAL_AREA = sum(AREA))
  return(list(CROP_AREAS))
}
clusterExport(cl,'intersect_2021')
results<- c(parLapply(cl,seq_id_all,fun=aggreg_function))
```

My preferred solution is to keep the piping structure of my syntax (tidyverse), but I suppose it might work to have a base R aggregation by two grouping factors, i.e. you could just have the aggregation as a short function in the parLapply call, but I was a little unsure how base R would treat an sf object. If there is no tidyverse solution, I would accept a base R solution. I can add that part of my problem is that while I am fairly proficient in tidyr and dplyr (though quasi quotation still confuses me…), I am not so proficient in purrr and I tend to write for-loops when I need to iterate over rows instead of using any of the apply family of functions from base R.

**Because my preference is to keep tidyverse syntax, my question is how can one parallelize aggregation of area calculations with two grouping variables on a large sf object using tidverse syntax on a Windows machine?** Below you will find code for a reproducible example that approximates my problem. The code below creates 10 km x 10 km grids over Sweden, and then creates random polygons that are randomly assigned to one of five group variables. The polygons are intersected with the grid cells, and the issue here is how to aggregate the areas for polygon slivers inside the grid cells with the same grouping factor. As mentioned, my actual use-case involves 1km x 1km grid cells over Sweden, but that would take too much time, so I have simplified the task somewhat in this example by using 10 km x 10 km grid cells.

```
### Reproducible example

library(raster)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

SWE <- getData('GADM', country = 'swe', level = 0) ### download outline of Sweden

SWE <- st_as_sf(SWE) ### convert to sf object

SWE <- st_transform(SWE, crs = 3006) ## proj = SWEREF 99        

### In my actual data, the grid squares are 1000 x 1000 meters but I make the grids 10000 X 10000 to make this go faster
grid_Sweden <- st_make_grid(SWE,
                            cellsize = c(10000, 10000),
                            crs = 3006,
                            what = "polygons",
                            square = T,
                            flat_topped = F)

grid_Sweden <- st_as_sf(grid_Sweden) ### convert to sf
grid_Sweden$ID_GRID <- seq(1, length(grid_Sweden$x), 1) ### create ID for each grid cell

grid_Sweden <- st_intersection(grid_Sweden, SWE) ### only keep grid cells that overlap with Sweden

grid_Sweden <- grid_Sweden[,c(1,4)] ### get rid of unnecessary columns


### now create random points within the bounding box, and then create polygons between the points

points_in_Sweden <- st_sample(SWE, 20000, type = "random", exact = T)

### Create polygons from the points
polygons_Swe <- points_in_Sweden %>% st_union() %>% st_voronoi %>% st_collection_extract() %>%
  st_sf(crs = 3006) 

GROUP_CATEGORY <- c("GROUP1", "GROUP2", "GROUP3", "GROUP4", "GROUP5") ### grouping categories

polygons_Swe$GROUP <- sample(GROUP_CATEGORY, size = nrow(polygons_Swe), replace = T) ### randomly distribute the grouping categories


### In my actual data, the polygons do not actually fill the grid squares (except in a few exceptional cases)
### so I randomly select some grids here to delete, so this looks more like my use case.

delete_rows <- sample(1:nrow(polygons_Swe), size = nrow(polygons_Swe)/5, replace = F) 
polygons_Swe <- polygons_Swe %>% slice(-delete_rows) 

### Then intersect the grid and the polygons
poly_in_grid <- st_intersection(grid_Sweden, polygons_Swe)

poly_in_grid <- mutate(poly_in_grid, AREA = st_area(poly_in_grid)) ### calculate the area of the polygon slivers in each grid

poly_in_grid <- poly_in_grid[, c(1,2,4,3)] ### rearrange the columns so that the geometry column is last

### Now I need to calculate area of each group per grid cell. This is what takes so long when I have 1 km grid cells, and what I want to parallelize 
### This example with 10 km by 10 km grid cells took about 18 minutes on my computer. My actual case, with 1 km x 1km grids, takes 3 hours


What_I_want <- poly_in_grid %>% group_by(ID_GRID, GROUP) %>% summarise(GROUP_AREA = sum(AREA))
```

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: There is a ticket open in tidyverse/multidplyr for {sf} support. There is no recent activity on it, but you can give it a thumb up to keep the pressure up https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr/issues/112

Comment: Define your grid as a `raster` and use `exactextractr::coverage_fraction` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/exactextractr/versions/0.6.1/topics/coverage_fraction)

Comment: "I will need to do this 10 times" - so write a script for each of the ten cases and launch them all from the command line as separate processes (start ten CMD windows if you have to)- you might save an RStudio memory overhead too. The OS will fill up your 8 cores and you can't do better than that.

Comment: @Spacedman I tried your suggestion. Running the operation on R usually takes 3 hours per case (i.e. one at a time), and when I initiate two cases from separate CMD windows per your suggestion, it takes 6 hours +/-. I can see that they are separate processes, but I wonder if they are using the same core after all. Is there a way to specify which core to use from the command line?

Comment: The windows monitoring tools (which I'm not familiar with since Windows XP was a thing) should tell you what % of your total CPU is being used and which cores. I doubt these were running on the same core (yes Windows is not the greatest OS, but even it should spot two independent processes can live on separate cores), and suspect your bottleneck isn't CPU, and probably disk access.